# How to make Airmail to open mailto: protocol link?

Tags: mail.app, macos

I have searched for this but I can't find anything in search results answering this query.

When I click on mailto link given in a mail inside Airmail,it opens Mail.app window instead of opening it inside Airmail. On setting gmail account on Mail.app, starts downloading 2GB sized inbox.

Comment: How about this https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201607 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) to tweak this type of setting and many other.  Note that while this is an older app nonetheless it still works with OS X 10.11.x too.

It's a Preferences Pane style app and it's freeware. You can read more about it and see screenshots at the web site (linked above).

Answer (score 2):

Open Mail >> Preferences >> General >> Default Email Reader (Select AirMail)

Comment: it works for few seconds immediately after changing it then again it start opening in Mail.app and when I check Prefs, it is Mail as default back again